# SemanticException: Table not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hive

we are trying to connect hive data base through spring boot, I am able to connect to hive data base but while executing the sql statement, we are getting as table not found, where actually table exist

```
Entity class is defined as below

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "site_text", schema = "text_data")
    public class Plants implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "site_text")
        private String siteName;
    }

Error as below-----
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:63 Table not found 'plants_text'
```

Comment: You show us an `@Entity` with name in `@Table` `site_text` and an error with table name `plants_text`. You are missing the query.

Comment: copy mistake, let me update error, org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 1:63 Table not found 'site_text